# How to combine two commands in Linux?

Tags: linux

How do I perform 2 commands within 1 line that the first perform action on the 2nd's result?
For example, if I want to remove all the results of a certain path list given to me by "locate" (`rm -rf > locate text.ext`), how would I go about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not far off :)  ... one way of doing it would be:

```
locate text.ext | xargs -i rm -rf "{}"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.